# The definition of generalized function (pde)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The definition of generalized function in my books is as follows:
generalized function is linear continuous function on fundamental spaces, such as $\mathbb{D}(R^n),\varphi(R^n)$.

But in ADAMS, the definition of generalized function means:
$\mathbb{D}'(R^n)$ (which is the linear continuous function on $\mathbb{D}(R^n)$, where $\mathbb{D}(R^n)$ means $C_c^\infty(R^n)$ )

so what is the exact definition of generalized function?
I'm so confused of it. Somebody can help me to make it clear? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a topological vector space, the notation $X'$ is used to represent its dual, that is, the space of continuous linear functionals on $X$. Then, $\Bbb D'(\Bbb R^n)$ is the space of linear continuous functions on $\Bbb D(\Bbb R^n)$. Both definitions coincide.

Comment: but in ADAMS generalized function means $D'(R^n)$, in the book 1, generalized function means $D'(R^n)$ or $φ(R^n)$ or any continuous function on fundamental space..

Comment: Haw does your book define $\varphi(\Bbb R^n)$ and fundamental space?